# Static SQL Server Indexes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, indexing

Is it possible to create unclustered indexes in SQL Server 2005 that are not updated as data is changed (insert/delete/udpate) so I can ensure a stable set of data to report on?

Our data is changing frequently an I want to be able to snapshot it at a point with out having a column to show the latest change date/time and only selecting data based on that.  Before I perform my analysis, I could update them and use them from that point forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can tell an index to remain stale.  A separate reporting table would be more appropriate solution.

For example, you can load a snapshot into a new reporting table like:

```
truncate table BigTableSnapshot

select *
from BigTable
into BigTableSnapshot
```

Alternatively, SQL Server Enterprise Edition allows you to take [snapshots](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-server-2005-snapshots/) of an entire database.  That can be very useful for reporting, although it does have a performance impact.

Comment: Its not quite the solution that I was looking for but I think that its the best that you can get in SQL Server.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Enterprise version of SQL2005 you can snapshot the whole database giving you a read-only / static point in time copy of the database to report against.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175158.aspx

Comment: Sorry Andomar, I didn't read you answer properly and see that you've already pointed this out.

Comment: @SuperCoolMoss: It's okay to post multiple answers!  The voters can decide which one explains it better